# Conditional redirect in ember before/upon page load

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to write some logic where if a user is logged in (and hence a `currentUser` variable is defined, more details in edit section below), he should not be able to access the root URL of the application, which is the log-in page.  I'm trying to achieve this using a redirect to the `users.show` page before/as soon as the page loads, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Reading ember documentation, you can do redirects from the route or the controller.  I've attempted both and neither have worked.  In the route:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  redirect: ->
    currentUser = @controllerFor('Application').get('currentUser') # this works
    currentPath = @controllerFor('Application').get('currentPath') # this returns undefined
    if currentUser && currentPath == '/'
      @transitionTo('users.show', currentUser)
```

The problem here is that I can't read the currentPath for some reason, even though I can access it from within `App.ApplicationController`.

In the controller, I've tried:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  init: -> # never gets called
    if @get('currentUser') && @get('currentPath') == '/'
      @transitionToRoute('users.show', @get('currentUser'))
```

Except the `init` never gets called when loading the page, and I can't figure out from the documentation which hook gets called on page load.

If there are any other problems with the code, feel free to point them out.  How do I fix my code in order to achieve the redirect?

**EDIT:** it was suggested for the route implementation to change `'application'` to lowercase in `@controllerFor('application')`.  Tried this and it returns the error

```
Assertion failed: The controller named 'application' could not be found. Make sure that this route exists and has already been entered at least once. If you are accessing a controller not associated with a route, make sure the controller class is explicitly defined.
```

Not sure what's going on, as doing a `@controllerFor` for other routes in all lowercase works, but not `'application'`.

The **Current User** variable is obtained via an injection in an ember initializer.  I'm using Rails and Devise on my backend, and the way I get `currentUser` into ember essentially more or less follows [this tutorial](http://say26.com/using-rails-devise-with-ember-js).  The general flow is Rails -> meta tag -> initializer -> injection.

**SOLUTION:** Inspired by the discussion following the accepted answer, I ended up doing it in `ApplicationRoute` like so:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: (transition) ->
    currentUser = @controllerFor('currentUser')
    if currentUser && transition.targetName == 'index'
        @transitionTo('users.show', currentUser)
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you capitalized `Application`. I don't know about user created routes, but the `application` route is definitely all lowercase.

Comment: See my edit to the bottom of original question.  It doesn't seem to like `@controllerFor('application')` within `App.ApplicationRoute`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see that you were trying to get the application controller from the application route. I'm not 100% sure that will work. I believe the `redirect` hook is called fairly early on in the routing process, before `setupController` is called. That means that your `init` method is unlikely to be called before your `redirect` hook.

I have two potential solutions:

1. It seems like the `currentUser` variable is created from some kind of global information. If that's the case, create it in the route, and transition if necessary. If you still want the data injected in the controller, use the `setupController` hook to put it there.
2. If the `currentUser` variable happens to be the model for that particular route, try transitioning in the `afterModel` hook instead. This way you'll have direct access to the data.

Also, I would try to avoid transitions like that in controllers. Try to keep them in the routes if possible.

If you can give me a little more information about where the `currentUser` variable comes from, I can probably give you a more specific answer.

EDIT: This piece of code comes from the article you posted:

```
controller = container.lookup('controller:currentUser').set('content', user)
```

If that's similar to what you're using, try injecting it into the route rather than the controller.

```
controller = container.lookup('route:currentUser').set('currentUserModel', user)
```

You can then just use `@get('currentUserModel')` right in your route. And, if for some reason that doesn't work, just place the user in the global scope, just to make sure you don't have other errors. So instead of the line above:

```
App.TEMP_CURRENT_USER = user;
```

Comment: I've added a section in the original question about `currentUser`.  It comes from injection within an initializer.  I don't actually know too much about the inner workings of injection (except that it more or less does what I want here, which is give each controller access to a `currentUser` variable), so it would be great if you could elaborate your answer based on this new information.  If you have a better way of implementing `currentUser` that also nicely solves the redirect problem, feel free to share also!

Comment: I updated my post. The gist is that in `Ember.Application.initializer`, you have the user model in the `user` variable. From there, you should be able to place it anywhere for easy access later.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  That line is indeed what I am using.  I can change it to what you suggested, but I don't think it solves my problem.  I can indeed already access the `currentUser` variable from the `ApplicationRoute` via `@controllerFor`, but the problem is that I can't get `currentPath`.  Maybe then the question becomes, what is the best way to get `currentPath` in the route?

Comment: Not really sure what `currentPath` is supposed to be. Is that supposed to be the current URL?

Comment: I believe `currentPath` is an attribute defined in the `ApplicationController` that returns the current URL.  If I'm in the `ApplicationRoute` and I want to redirect only when the user is at the home page, I need to check for that somehow, right?

Comment: I believe the best way to do that would be to use the `beforeModel` hook. The first parameter is the `transition` parameter. You'll have to inspect the `transition` parameter in your debugger, as I can't recall off the top of my head, but it has a variable equivalent to the `currentPath` you need. From there, you can use `this.transitionTo` to redirect if you need.

Comment: Thank you!  Got it to work.  Added the actual line of code in original question for reference.